# Dungeon Board Game rules scenario

Tags: dungeon

We're new to the game, and already ran across something that struck us as an issue. Here's the scenario:

- Wizard stops just shy of a room, fires in a spell that fails to kill the monster. He stays outside the room.
- On the next player's turn, he walks through the wizard and into the room to battle the monster (rules say heroes can pass through the same space, but not occupy it unless it's a chamber). Hero fights the monster, loses, but is not ejected from the room.
- Wizard's next turn comes. What can the wizard do now? The way the rules read, if he fires a spell into the room and kills the monster, he enters the room to loot, but the room is already occupied by the other hero, so the wizard is forbidden entry. Even worse, the wizard is still just outside the room.

What happens if during the combat in the room, the hero who pushed past is forced out of the room? Technically, the wizard was already in the space just outside the door, and there is nowhere for the hero to retreat to.

Answer (score 2):

The older [TSR version of the rules](http://files.geekdo.com/geekfile_download.php?filetype=application%2Fpdf&filename=DUNGEON!.pdf&filecode=24h7dh83e&validationcode=0cf09ab622fd31a0c950cddc8e724d2c) make this process a bit clearer:

> Die roll: 4-5-6; Light Wound!  Drop any 1  treasure card. Retreat back to the nearest empty corridor space. Lose one turn.